# Is each edge location in its own VPC (AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

In AWS,when a client enters a URL, this is sent to the DNS Resolver. Once the IP is retrieved, it is sent back to the client. CloudFront then redirects the request to the nearest edge location where the ELB routes the request to an EC2 Instance. Is each edge location in its own VPC?

Comment: The term VPC does simply not apply here. A VPC is a construct you create to place e.g. compute resources into. It has nothing to do with cloudfront or edge locations.

Comment: If you are attempting to describe how CloudFront works, then it would be more like "A client enters a URL that points to CloudFront. An IP address is returned that points to an appropriate CloudFront edge location. Traffic is then served from the edge location or, if it is not available in the edge cache, it is served from a regional cache or, failing that, the data is retrieved from the Origin, stored in the region and edge cache and returned to the client."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloudfront and VPC are two entirely different concepts.

A VPC is simply a network abstraction. It has nothing to do with how Amazon is handling caching & it's edge locations.

Amazon has multiple physical locations all across the world that acts as edge locations. Where you place your VPC (region) doesn't really matter in relation to how Cloudfront is able to serve traffic.